# Postgresql Aurora DB freeable_memory

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have a question regarding the freeable memory for AWS Aurora Postgres.

We recently wanted to create an index on one of our dbs and the db died and made a failover to the slave which all worked fine. It looks like the freeable memory dropped by the configured 500mb of maintenance_work_mem and by that went to around 800mb of memory - right after that the 32gig instance died.

1) I am wondering if the memory that is freeable is the overall system memory and if a low memory here could invoke the system oom killer on the AWS Aurora instance? So we may want to plan in more head room for operational tasks and the running of autovacuum jobs to not encounter this issue again?

2) The actual work of the index creation should then have used the free local storage as far as I understood, so the size of the index shouldn't have mattered, right?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 1)

Freeable Memory from (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=209720)

> The freeable memory includes the amount of physical memory left unused
>   by the system plus the total amount of buffer or page cache memory
>   that are free and available.
>
> So it's freeable memory across the entire system. While MySQL is the
>   main consumer of memory on the host we do have internal processes in
>   addition to the OS that use up a small amount of additional memory.
>
> If you see your freeable memory near 0 or also start seeing swap usage
>   then you may need to scale up to a larger instance class or adjust
>   MySQL memory settings. For example decreasing the
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size (by default set to 75% of physical memory) is
>   one way example of adjusting MySQL memory settings.

That also means that if the memory gets low its likely to impact the process in some form. In this thread (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=881320&#881320) e.g. it was mentioned that it caused the mysql server to restart.

Regarding 2)

This is like it is described in the documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/postgresql-aurora-storage-issue/) so I guess its right and the size shouldn't have mattered.

> Storage used for temporary data and logs (local storage). All DB
>   temporary files (for example, logs and temporary tables) are stored in
>   the instance local storage. This includes sorting operations, hash
>   tables, and grouping operations that are required by queries.
>
> Each Aurora instance contains a limited amount of local storage that
>   is determined by the instance class. Typically, the amount of local
>   storage is twice the amount of memory on the instance. If you perform
>   a sort or index creation operation that requires more memory than is
>   available on your instance, Aurora uses the local storage to fulfill
>   the operation.